# open image gallery page on button click

Tags: android, android-activity, gridview

I am creating food shop app in which click on menu button on home page it should redirect to grid view ,

[image]

i have created image grid layout xml and image grid class , but not able to map it with button on home page

this is my main activity

```
public class TimmyRestaurantActivity extends Activity {

    Button go_to_menu,go_to_order_list,findstore,info;
    //Button custinfo;
    String user_name;
    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Intent myintent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = myintent.getExtras();
        user_name = extras.getString("cust_name");
        Toast.makeText(TimmyRestaurantActivity.this, "Welcome " + user_name ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

       // initialise form widget
        go_to_menu=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Go_To_Menu);


        go_to_menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i=new Intent(TimmyRestaurantActivity.this, 
     ImageAdapter.class);
            startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

this is my gridlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

</GridView>
```

this is adaptor class for my grid

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.img15, R.drawable.img15,
            R.drawable.img15, R.drawable.img15
    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

and on menuscreen.java i am trying call my gridadapater

```
public class MenuScreen extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

}
```

on click button , this error comes

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.restaurant/com.restaurant.MenuScreen}: 
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ExpandableListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

How can i properly redirect from home page button to grid view page , please suggest

Comment: What happens when you click on the button? Nothing? Does it crash or show a blank screen?

Comment: it crashes ..........i also tried one more alternate code , edited

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: error comes in logcat "Your content must have a ExpandableListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'"

Comment: You are not starting Activity.class which contains gridview, instead you are calling start Activity with ImageAdapter.class. Check your code once

Answer (score 0):

Add a placeholder in your main laout(R.layout.main)

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/place_men"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

and chnage the code like

```
go_to_menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //starting new fragment on button click
               MenuScreen menuScreen =new MenuScreen();

 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.place_men, menuScreen).commit();
            }
        });
```

Also MenuScreen  extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Answer (score 0):

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f0f0f0">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

grid_item_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

GridViewAdapter.class

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private Context context;
private int layoutResourceId;
private ArrayList data = new ArrayList();

public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    ImageItem item = data.get(position);
    holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView image;
}
}
```

ImageItem.class pojo class

```
public class ImageItem {
private Bitmap image;
private String title;

public ImageItem(Bitmap image, String title) {
    super();
    this.image = image;
    this.title = title;
}

public Bitmap getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private GridView gridView;
private GridViewAdapter gridAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());
    gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
}

// Prepare some dummy data for gridview
private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
    final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
    TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.image_ids);
    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length(); i++) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
        imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap, "Image#" + i));
    }
    return imageItems;
}
}
```

Please follow this code implementation for Gridview

And in your button click event

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

         }
     });
```

Follow this link for working example

[Image GridView](http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android)

Comment: this will show grid on first page , or on second page after button redirect ?

Comment: I edited my code, this will show grid in second Activity

Comment: follow the button clicklistener method, it will solve your problem.

Comment: this is big and different code  , wont it changes my home screen ?

Comment: I have given only gridview code.

This code should be in your home page

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

         }
     });

Comment: but wont main activity layout and class code will change my home screen ?

Comment: your button.setOnClickListener code is already put in my code

Comment: YYep, but did you observe the difference